# Prevent automated starting of Android app due to “machine learning” (Samsung's PkgPredictorService)

Tags: android, autostart, samsung-galaxy

I am the developer of an app and it's available and working well since about two years.

Only on recent Samsung devices the app gets randomly started by the system after the user closed it via its exit button. This exit button stops all services and activities and kills the app via Android's "killProcess"-method,so it's not a simple restart of a crashed app. It's an utility-app which runs in the background and if the user closes it, it must stop and stay closed because it produces a lot of traffic in the background. Maybe there's something I can add to the manifest-file?

Samsung's "PkgPredictorService: [com.samsung.android.nextapp.IPkgPredictor]" seems to silently start my app based on "machine learning":

```
    165668  08-17 18:41:58.843  4971  5299 D PkgPredictorService-NapPreloadController: preload pkg: [] type: ml
    165669  08-17 18:41:58.843  4971  5299 D PkgPredictorService-NapPreloadController: Sent pkg = eu.abc.pro type: ml
    165670  08-17 18:41:58.844  4971  5665 D ActivityManager: [ML] packageName : eu.abc.pro uid : 0 type : ml
    165672  08-17 18:41:58.844  4971  5665 D ActivityManager: [ML]launchEmptyProcess packageName :eu.abc.pro, userId : 0, type :ml
    165674  08-17 18:41:58.847  4971  5665 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:eu.abc.pro user:0
    165676  08-17 18:41:58.847  4971  5665 D ActivityManager: package  eu.abc.pro, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
    165677  08-17 18:41:58.847  4971  5665 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:eu.abc.pro user:0
    165679  08-17 18:41:58.847  4971  5665 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:eu.abc.pro user:0
    165684  08-17 18:41:58.848  4971  4971 D PkgPredictorService-NapPreloadController: Get reply pkgName = eu.abc.pro type = ml uid = 0
    165686  08-17 18:41:58.864  4971  5048 I ActivityManager: Start proc 18318:eu.abc.pro/u0a447 for mllaunch {eu.abc.pro/eu.abc.activities.MainActivity}
```

I don't want the app to get started without user interaction!

How can I disable/prevent that any machine learning algorithm starts my app automatically?

Comment: Why has this question been closed? I do clearly ask for help for a particular issue.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you, *How to keep Samsung's PkgPredictorService from pre-loading my app* seems like an on topic question. But could you add exactly why you want to stop preloading? What is it breaking?

Comment: This is a coding website.  Normally, we require code for troubleshooting questions.

Comment: I don't know how you'd include any code when asking about the potential existence of an API or a workaround for the lack of an API.

Comment: This is probably a question for Android or Superuser; what is programmatic about stopping a Samsung service from auto-running on a Samsung device? For example, how to disable a service on Windows is not a Stack Overflow question but rather a Superuser one. Unless OP can clarify how they expect programming to be involved in a way described by the Help Center, I don't see this as on-topic here.

Comment: @TylerH Strong disagree — Android and Superuser are for questions by _users_.  This is a question about a programmatic API by a developer who wants to change the behavior of the application by talking to the OS. The way you do that is with _code_.

Comment: @MattB. I don't see any indication here that OP is trying to develop anything or that OP is using a programming API. It seems to me OP is observing from log data that a service is starting automatically and they want to stop that from happening. If OP means "an app I developed" by "my app", then OP needs to show the relevant code from that app based on this log dump so we can help find the root cause. Otherwise this is a problem at the *user* interface level.

Comment: Thanks for reopening. I will add some more information to the description.

Comment: Same problem. My app can;t start without user interaction and so it fails, eating battery, and crazy mllaunch restarts it....