# What is the use case for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED given Jetpack's App Startup library?

Tags: android-intent, android-jetpack

What is the use case for [android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) given Jetpack's [App Startup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup) library?

One thought is that if you need something to run in a separate process then that can be done with a BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver but not with the App Startup library

Another thought is alarms, but I'm not clear if alarms are cleared on app updates etc. i.e. whether alarms are best set in App Startup initializers or BOOT_COMPLETED receivers

Comment: To clarify, I was under the impression that all ContentProviders are started at device boot, but this is not true. They are only started at process start. Only some devices will auto start some app processes at boot even if they do not have BOOT_COMPLETED receiver. For example, recently Samsung devices do this with some "ML boost" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579509/prevent-automated-starting-of-android-app-due-to-machine-learning-samsungs-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetpack App Startup is a library that helps you initialize components in your app when the app starts.

On the other hand, the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is a way for the system to let you know that the device has booted.

Those two scenarios are rather different. Depending on your situation you might want to use either respectively.

Comment: Yes, you're right. ContentProviders (and so, Initializers) are started at process start and the app process can be started by the device under various scenarios. Samsung uses ML to start some apps at device boot even those that do not have a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver. A BOOT_COMPLETED receiver can optionally be started in a separate process which is something beyond the capabilities of the App Startup library AFAICT. Anyway, I agree they are quite different.